# Is it safe to use a soldering gun when attempting solder repairs to a PCB with IC chips and other processing units?

Tags: motherboard

I have a laptop that needs to have a part repaired. I have a roughly 20 or 30 watt soldering iron, but it seems to take so long just to melt the solder onto the eyelet. Holding it there for so long causes me to wonder if I might be damaging sensitive components nearby.

So I got this idea. A soldering gun heats and cools very quickly, which means I can apply the tip to the eyelet, put the solder onto the eyelet, or whatever metal contact I have to apply solder too, and then compress the switch to turn on the heat. It heats up pretty quickly, so it'll melt the solder, and once that is done, I can immediately remove the soldering gun tip and solder string, allowing the gun's tip to cool before applying solder to the next part.

I was in Job Corps, and I did electrical assembly. I had chosen to build one of those hobbyist electronics assembly multimeter kits as the part to the class, however, it didn't work properly, and I couldn't figure out what I did wrong. My conclusion was that I must have damaged the IC chip when applying solder. I probably applied the iron for too long to the eyelet in order to melt the solder to it.

Since then, this has always been a problem. I have to apply the soldering iron for several seconds just to get the solder to melt onto the eyelet. By that time, I fear I am destroying components. I know, I could try and melt the solder onto the iron, and let it flow onto the eyelet that way, but I distinctly remember reading that that is the wrong way. The solder must melt onto the contact in order to ensure proper melding with the contact metal.

This is why I thought the gun my help me. It will surely allow the solder to melt rather rapidly, and I can remove it as soon as the solder has melted. It should be far quicker than a soldering iron.

Feel free to make recommendations, as I am not by any means skilled nor experienced in soldering components.

However, my primary question that I'd like answered is whether a soldering gun is safe using it in the manner that I have illustrated above. BTW, the PCB is a laptop motherboard in which the CR 2032 battery housing has become detached from the contacts, and I must reattach it after drawing a new metal lead with a PCB pen.

Comment: Get a temperature controlled iron [like this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11704).  You will not believe the difference.

Answer (score 3):

I would not use soldering gun to solder onto any PCB (*it simply does not control the temperature, fast variations/**not good***). That is not the purpose of the gun. There are better tools for soldering, like soldering iron. I fear that the soldering gun can actually do more damage to the mainboard than the soldering iron.

I replaced capacitors on my PC mainboard using soldering iron @ 300 degrees Celsius.
To make your soldering succesfull, apply a little solder onto the iron tip, then quickly place it on the solder place for CR2032 (**!!! battery must be removed!!!**). Add more solder to finish the soldering proccess.

I don't think that soldering the ic for less than 10s can damage the IC (rare), but you should try to be quick as possible. Soldering other components, like battery holder, would not damage other components.

You could apply some soldering flux to the soldering points of the holder. Use quality soldering iron, be as quick as possible and good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Triak. I don't think that a soldering gun is a solution. The reason why is that it does not have any feedback to control the tip temperature. It may damage the PCB traces as well as the IC.

The right solution is to have a soldering station, which controls your tip temperature. To solder an IC, you should not need either a high temperature setting or a heavy duty tip (large thermal mass). The soldering process should not take more than 3 seconds, if it does there is something wrong with your system or your technique.

Possible mistakes are an iron tip that is oxidized, using a solder wire that does not have flux, a low quality one or even if it is lead free. Concerning your technique, you may not be touching both the pad and the IC terminal at the same time. There are tons of videos on YouTube about how to solder. I personally recommend the one from eevBlog.

Comment: Comment about touching the pad and pin at same time is a good one. In school I'd see people doing that a lot, touching the tip to the top of the ic pin so it was getting almost all of the heat. I usually make sure to hit mostly the pad with the solder iron tip as it usually takes longer to heat. Another thing is to use a smaller tip on the iron. Seeing people try to use a huge tip to solder a small pad is always painful.

Answer (score 0):

Although a soldering gun is not the ideal tool for PCB work, it can work well *IF* you are careful.  You are right to worry about your soldering iron not having enough heat capacity to reliably make solder connections to your PCB, especially large pads.  Keeping a soldering iron that isn't hot enough to melt the solder on the pad is a sure-fire way to cause the pad to lift off the board.

Best option is to have someone else who has the proper equipment to do the actual soldering for you.  This should cost you approximately nothing if you have already disassembled the unit down to the PCB by itself.

Next best option is to replace the battery holder (if it is damaged) and then use thin insulated wire to connect the terminals to the proper nodes on the board.  I find that pens filled with conductive liquid do NOT make reliable, long-term connections when used to repair missing traces or pads on circuit boards.  Use glue to hold the battery holder in its' location if needed.  Hot-melt glue works well for this and is removable if you need to do so later.

The two main problems with a soldering gun is the large tip size and the uncontrolled amount of heat that it produces.  Nonetheless, it CAN be used to make a reliable repair *IF* you are extremely careful.

One final note: there is a significant probability that your soldering gun has significant leakage current from the AC Mains to the tip.  The cure for this is to ground one side of the tip to Earth ground.